# Should ArcGIS change the path of a gdb to the server data store when publishing a GP service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service, error-000732

I've published a GP service to ArcGIS server and it fails when I try to run it. The workspace is a file GDB on the local network, and the script contains a UNC path to it. There is a copy of the data on the server, and this GDB is referenced in the data store. See screenshot below.
[image: Data Store Settings]

Now I'm trying to call this service using the Javascript API and the service fails with "ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset AE010S010_020M6004P01M010 does not exist or is not supported."

I've found the python script on the server and the workspace path is still set to the UNC path in the original script. The problem is that when running the GP service, the user is local to the server and does not have access to domain resources, so cannot see the network GDB.

The question is, should ArcGIS change the workspace path in the script to D:\data? I thought that was the whole point of adding a data store entry to the server.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. I've always checked "Same as publisher folder path" for the Server folder path. Did you try that? Also does the ArcGIS Server account have access to the share?

Comment: That's correct, it is a permissions issue. The share is not available to the server account by design, as this site is available to external clients. We don't want to open up our local domain to the general internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out this is a known issue - [NIM098733](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDk4NzMz). It's fixed at 10.3 and there are no plans for porting back to earlier versions, so if, like me, you're on 10.2.1, you'll need to upgrade.